# How to create a CBTHook in jni and then call a java function in the callback function?

Tags: java, c, callback, java-native-interface

Update (23/02/13): Tested the Hook separatedly, it works. The problem was that you can't use `printf` in a .dll, unless you associate a console with it.

I instead replaced every `printf` with `fprintf` and wrote the output in a logfile.

Update (22/02/13): Initialized the variable `clazz` in a correct way.

I want to call a method in my java application, if any desktop window is `created/activated/destroyed`.

I wrote a simple Java class with two native functions:

```
public class Hook {

public Hook(){}

public void setstatus(){
    System.out.println("status set");
}

public native void starthook();
public native void stophook();
}
```

And in C I wrote the following:

```
#include "Hook.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HHOOK   g_hHook  = NULL;
FILE *pFile=NULL;
//do mid, clazz and jvm have to be shared ?
//jmethodID mid=NULL;
//jclass clazz=NULL;
//static JavaVM *jvm = NULL;

#pragma data_seg()

HINSTANCE   g_hInstance = NULL;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved ){
    switch (ul_reason_for_call){
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstance  = (HINSTANCE) hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:  break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:  break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);       
    /*
    JNIEnv *env;
    int res =(*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm,(void **)&env, NULL);
        if(res<0){
            fprintf(pFile,"AttachCurrentThread failed\n");
            return 0;
        }
    */

    HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
    if (!hWnd){
        fprintf(pFile,"hWnd==NULL\n");
        //(*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
        return 0;
    }
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE){            
        // is printed
        fprintf(pFile,"activated\n");
        // isn't called
        //(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, mid);
        // Nothing is logged
        //if((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env))
        //      (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
    }
    else if (nCode == HCBT_DESTROYWND){
        fprintf(pFile,"destroyed\n");
    }
    else if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND){
        fprintf(pFile,"created\n");
    }
    //(*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
    return 0;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hook_starthook(JNIEnv *e, jobject o){
/*
if(jvm==NULL)
    if(((*e)->GetJavaVM(e,&jvm))<0){
        printf("GetJavaVM failed\n");
        return;
        }
    jclass localRef = (*e)->GetObjectClass(e, o);
        clazz = (*e)->NewGlobalRef(e,localRef);
    if(clazz==NULL){
        printf("GetObjectClass failed\n");
        return;
    }
    mid = (*e)->GetMethodID(e, clazz, "setstatus", "()V");
    if(mid==0){
        printf("GetMethodID failed\n");
        return;
    }
*/
    pFile = fopen("C:/workspace/CBTHook/log.txt","a");
    g_hHook      = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC) CBTProc, g_hInstance, 0);
    printf("Hook started\n");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hook_stophook(JNIEnv *e, jobject o){
    if (g_hHook){
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        g_hHook = NULL;
        //(*e)->DeleteGlobalRef(e,clazz);
    }
    if(pFile)
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    printf("Hook stopped\n");
}
```

The `CBTHook` works, but I can't call the `setstatus` function from within the `callback` function.

```
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, mid);
```

doesn't do anything and no Exception is thrown.

What do I have to do ?

Furthermore do I have to share the global variables: `mid`, `clazz` and `jvm` ?
Every variable in the

```
#pragma data_seg("SHARED")
```

segment is "shared", which means that they are not unique to a specific process.

And what would be the correct way to attach/detach the other threads, if this is necessary?

Comment: You should solve the problems one by one. I understand that you are not even sure that your hook is called every time, for every window. So leave out all dependencies on JNI, call `SetWindowHookEx` from `DllMain` and come back when it works reliably. We can work on the JNI callback then.

Comment: Hey, the hook works. See updates in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of clear explanation about what "*don't receive messages*" exactly means, i will speculate that your `CBTProc` **is being called**, and you just don't get the JVM callback. *If `CBTProc` is not called, then it's not a JNI problem at all*.

You did it almost right. `jmethodID` is reusable between threads and between JNI calls, so it can be cached as you did. The way you get `JavaVM*` in `starthook()` and cache it is also correct. You are only wrong about `jclass clazz`. You try to cache it in `starthook()` and then try to use it not only in different call, but most probably even in different thread. What you get from `GetObjectClass` is a *local reference* which means that it's validity is not ensured after the current JNI call exits back to JVM. It might work, but you can't rely on it. And it *definitely* won't work when used from different thread. You must make a *global reference*:

```
jclass localRef = (*e)->GetObjectClass(e,o);
clazz = (*e)->NewGlobalRef(e,localRef);
```

Then you can use `clazz` in the way you already have in `CBTProc` commented out. The only work left is in `stophook`:

```
(*e)->DeleteGlobalRef(e,clazz);
```

So that it doesn't leak.

**Bottom note**: i don't understand what you mean by "*sharing the global variables*".

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. What I meant with "don't receive messages" was that for example "printf("activated\n");" in the callback function is printed if the window of my java application is activated, but it's not printed if a window of a different application is activated. Process Viewer shows that the Hook.dll was hooked in that application. I made a global reference and then tried to call "(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, mid);" but now, if I place "(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, mid);" above "printf("activated\n");", nothing is printed. See next comment...

Comment: If I do it reversed then "printf("activated\n");" is printed, but "(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, clazz, mid);" still doesn't do anything. In addition I ask if an Exception occured, but nothing is logged. What I meant with "sharing global variables" was the "#pragma data_seg("SHARED")" segment. Every variable in that segment is "shared", which means that they are not unique to a specific process. My question was, if every variable I put in that segment has to be shared. PS: Sorry for my bad English. PPS: I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet -.-

Comment: S.O. procedural hint: if you're asked for clarification, add it to your original post and perhaps title it "Update" or such. Comments are not meant for it, the worse if it contains code. It's unreadable.